# If sql have counted specific people with COUNT(), how should i know who these selected people are using their id?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

If sql have counted specific people with COUNT(), how should i know who these selected people are using their id using this query?
For example, if it counted 5 nonhmsonboard, who are they/what are their ids?

```
                SELECT long_posname,            
                COUNT( 
                CASE WHEN employment_status LIKE  'ON BOARD' and trim(groupID)='grp320952d8919d763a8'
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
                END ) AS  'hmsonboard',

                COUNT( 
                CASE WHEN employment_status LIKE  'VACATION' and trim(groupID)='grp320952d8919d763a8'
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
                END ) AS  'hmsonvacation',

                COUNT( 
                CASE WHEN employment_status LIKE  'ON BOARD' and trim(groupID)='grp320952d8919d763a8'
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
                END ) + COUNT( 
                CASE WHEN employment_status LIKE  'VACATION' and trim(groupID)='grp320952d8919d763a8'
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
                END ) AS  'hmstotal',

                COUNT( 
                CASE WHEN employment_status LIKE  'ON BOARD' and trim(groupID)!='grp320952d8919d763a8'
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
                END ) AS  'nonhmsonboard',

                COUNT( 
                CASE WHEN employment_status LIKE  'VACATION' and trim(groupID)!='grp320952d8919d763a8'
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
                END ) AS  'nonhmsonvacation',

                COUNT( 
                CASE WHEN employment_status LIKE  'ON BOARD' and trim(groupID)!='grp320952d8919d763a8'
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
                END ) + COUNT( 
                CASE WHEN employment_status LIKE  'VACATION' and trim(groupID)!='grp320952d8919d763a8'
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
                END ) AS  'nonhmstotal',

                COUNT( 
                CASE WHEN employment_status LIKE  'ON BOARD'
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
                END ) + COUNT( 
                CASE WHEN employment_status LIKE  'VACATION'
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
                END ) AS  'total', crewID

                FROM (

                SELECT tb_crew_master.groupID, tb_crew_master.crewID, MAX( date_arrive ) , tb_crew_master.empstatID, pl_employment_status.employment_status, long_posname, pos_arrangement, tb_crew_master.posID
                FROM tb_crew_master
                INNER JOIN tb_crew_seaservice ON tb_crew_master.crewID = tb_crew_seaservice.crewID
                INNER JOIN pl_position ON pl_position.posID = tb_crew_master.posID
                INNER JOIN pl_employment_status ON pl_employment_status.empstatID = tb_crew_master.empstatID
                INNER JOIN tb_vessel ON tb_vessel.vesID = tb_crew_seaservice.vesID 
                INNER JOIN pl_vessel_type ON pl_vessel_type.vestypeID = tb_vessel.vestypeID
                WHERE tb_crew_master.is_inactive = 'N' and pl_vessel_type.vestypeID='typ249225370585e575f8'
                GROUP BY tb_crew_seaservice.crewID 
                ) AS t
                GROUP BY posID
                ORDER BY pos_arrangement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but use the `crewID` column (assuming from your posted query code) or any other 
`ID` column from respective table (ID column from `pl_employment_status` table) like

```
            SELECT crewID,
            long_posname,            
            COUNT( 
            CASE WHEN employment_status LIKE  'ON BOARD' 
            and trim(groupID)='grp320952d8919d763a8'
            THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
            END ) AS  'hmsonboard',

            .......

             <Rest of your code>

            .........


            GROUP BY crewID,long_posname
            ORDER BY pos_arrangement
```

Comment: @ralphcuneta_user3530269, no offense but don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.